How to typecheck for Constructor Signatures vs a regular function in Typescript?
My factory function below should accept both calls:
const instance1 = factory( MyClass );
const instance2 = factory( ()=> new MyClass() );

How can I differentiate this at runtime?   (please see "<What goes here?>" in the code)
type Constructor<T> = new () => T

const factory = <T>(arg: (() => T) | Constructor<T> ) =>{
  return (  <What comes here?>   ) ? new arg() : arg();
};


You really can't, not in any sane way. Push back on any use case that apparently requires this. Anyway since this is essentially a runtime question, this question is really about JS. See linked q/a for more info.
